# Is there any command I can use to disable brightness adjustments?

Tags: macos, imac

Is there any terminal command or script I can use to disable brightness adjustment system wide? I currently manage a large network of computers for a school district and we are looking for an easy solution to disable access to that functionality.

Comment: In all my years managing computers in schools, I've never had the need to disable this feature. Are students misbehaving by dimming the monitors?

Answer (score 1):

You might also run

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/serverhorror/brightness/master/brightness.c>brightness.c;gcc -std=c99 -o /usr/local/bin/brightness brightness.c -framework IOKit -framework ApplicationServices`

and then add

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/brightness -v 0.5
```

to crontab to reset the brightness to 50% every minute.

You can disable the brightness keys with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following AppleScript will turn the brightness all the way up and then disable adaptive brightness.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    -- launch
    -- activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of current pane
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            tell group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
                set value of slider 1 to 1.0 -- max
                tell checkbox 1
                    if value is 1 then click
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit -- optional
end tell
```

[Source.](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24018208)

Comment: Is there any way to disable non-administrators ability to use the keyboard buttons?

Comment: I don't believe so, short of remapping those function keys to other keys with a tool such as [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). You might be able to get away with enabling the setting `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` in System Preferences -> Keyboard. The second option wouldn't *disable* those keys, but might confuse a user into not knowing how to change the brightness.